# How to interpret the variant of the expression "sich um etw. Sorgen machen"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Ihr glaubt ja gar nicht, **was** ich mir **für** Sorgen um Euch gemacht habe!

How does this construction compare to:

> sich um etw. Sorgen machen

I'm puzzled by two small changes:

1. The "was" has taken the place of the "Sorgen" as the direct object.
2. The preposition "für" is now placed before "Sorgen".

Personally, I would express the same idea as below, keeping the construction "sich um etw. Sorgen machen":

> Ihr glaubt ja gar nicht, **wie viele Sorgen** ich mir um Euch gemacht habe!

Answer (score 5):

> Ihr glaubt ja gar nicht, **was** ich mir **für** Sorgen um euch gemacht habe!
>
> Ihr glaubt ja gar nicht, **was für** Sorgen ich mir um euch gemacht habe!
>
> Ihr glaubt ja gar nicht, **welche** Sorgen ich mir um euch gemacht habe!

In this example, **was für** is a fixed phrase meaning **welche**. But the latter sentences sound a bit *ungelenk* because of the *ich mir um euch* pronoun cluster. That's the reason *welche* had been replaced by *was für* and that one had been split into two parts.

---

There's another reason to use *was für* instead of *welcher/welche/welches*. It's about asking for a known or unknown thing, or a thing vs. a kind of thing:

> **Welches** Kleid ziehst du an? *(which of the ones I know of?)*
>
> **Was für** ein Kleid ziehst du an? *(which kind of dress?)*

---

In both uses, **was für** is a question word of its own, meaning **what kind**.